# Show Hide with jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to make it possible minimize and maximize option on title when user click on any title.
I am not good with jQuery.

[image]

My example link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjhAE/)

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>jsFiddle demo</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<style type='text/css'>
body {
    min-width: 520px;
}
.column {
    width: 170px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.portlet {
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
.portlet-header {
    margin: 0.3em;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 0.2em;
}
.portlet-header .ui-icon {
    float: right;
}
.portlet-content {
    padding: 0.4em;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    visibility: visible !important;
    height: 50px !important;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder * {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function () {
    $(".column").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column"
    });

    $(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
        .find(".portlet-header")
        .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
        .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
        .end()
        .find(".portlet-content");

    $(".portlet-header .ui-icon").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
        $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
    });

    $(".column").disableSelection();
});
});//]]>
</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">Feeds</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">Shopping</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">Links</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">Images</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I will thankful If anyone can help me :)

Comment: it already minimizes when you click the `+/-` beside the title...

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3J5RQ/

Comment: you should use slideToggle() for better effect: http://jsfiddle.net/cjhAE/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to use the whole title bar and not just the +/- icon, change:

```
$(".portlet-header .ui-icon").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
    $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
});
```

to

```
$(".portlet-header").click(function () {
    $(this).find('.ui-icon').toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
    $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cjhAE/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjhAE/1/)

```
 $(".portlet-header").click(function () {
        $(this).find('.ui-icon').toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
        $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
    });
```